# Why do file permissions show different in Python and bash?

Tags: python, bash, shell, command-line, stat

From **Python**:

```
>>> import os
>>> s = os.stat( '/etc/termcap')
>>> print( oct(s.st_mode) )
**0o100444**
```

When I check through **Bash**:

```
$ stat -f "%p %N" /etc/termcap
**120755** /etc/termcap
```

Why does this return a different result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because your /etc/termcap is a **symlink**.
Let me demonstrate this to you:

**Bash**:

```
$ touch bar
$ ln -s bar foo
$ stat -f "%p %N" foo
120755 foo
$ stat -f "%p %N" bar
100644 bar
```

**Python**:

```
>>> import os
>>> oct(os.stat('foo').st_mode)
'0100644'
>>> oct(os.stat('bar').st_mode)
'0100644'
>>> oct(os.lstat('foo').st_mode)
'0120755'
>>> oct(os.lstat('bar').st_mode)
'0100644'
```

Conclusion, use `os.lstat` instead of `os.stat`